# C++ regex for string "M0.89"

Tags: c++, regex

Trying to represent the following in a C++ regex: M0.89 or m1.78 or M0.9

```
"M|m([0-9].[0-9]+)"
```

Regex checking programs show that it is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way you are using the alternation operator. On the left side (1st alternative), it's only looking to match the letter "M" literally. On the right side (2nd alternative), it's looking for "m" followed by a numeric character → any single character and then another numeric character.

Any easy way would be to use a character class here:

```
"[mM][0-9]\\.[0-9]+"
```

**Note:** To match a literal `.`, you need to precede it with double backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

`"(M|m)([0-9]\\.[0-9]+)"` is what you're looking for. `.` without the escaping `\` will match any character, not just a literal period, and the parenthesis are needed around `M|m` to capture as you intended

If you don't want to capture the `M` as a group you could use `"[mM]([0-9]\\.[0-9]+)"`